# Changed username, now tweets won't show in search

Tags: twitter

I finally signed up to Twitter on the 5th of September and starting tweeting. I changed my name and username the next day and continued tweeting as normal, but when I put words into the search engine that I know appear in my tweets I don't show anywhere. I have read helpdesk on site and I have taken on board all their suggestions (don't be set to private, etc.) and have not tweeted any links or anything that could be considered spam, but after a couple of days my tweets or indeed my new username aren't showing in search.

Can someone please let me know if it is normal for there to be a delay in tweets filtering onto the system after you change username details, and if so how long before they start to trickle onto the system and people can view them.

Please let me know this is common and not me being thick. Any help would be great.

Comment: What's the username?

Comment: @BedsitContessa1, changed from JuliaRQThacker.

Answer (score 1):

It seems any status after Sep 6 7 am from your account hasn't been put in the search. I tried the same with a few accounts (including mine) so it's safe assumption to say the tweets will not appear in search for a few days or the fact that it's a new account has something to do with it.

To be fair, Twitter search is hit and miss sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I don't mind a delay if it's common with new starters on the site or if you change certain information. I've reported it via the site (not the most helpful system I've ever encountered) already, but it's nice to know it isn't just me that is affected. I'll wait a few days, tweeting as normal, and come back to pester webapps if it isn't better.